# Can external apps modify SSO settings?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Can an app external to a G-Suite organization manage its SSO settings?

I started by trying to create a client ID/secret for my app as per https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849

A prerequisite for getting a client ID/secret is configuring the app's Consent Screen as per https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#userconsent

When looking at the "Add Scope" modal, I only see:

```
Admin SDK   ../auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly
Admin SDK   ../auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly
```

How do I get a scope that would allow my app write access to another G-Suite  organization's SSO settings?

I am not trying to manage my G-Suite organization's SSO settings.

Comment: According to this post https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/10/shutdown-of-gdata-admin-settings-api.html a new API should have been released but can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want cannot be achieved essentially because you **cannot** manage someone else's G-Suite organization's SSO settings. Therefore, no scopes are available for this option.

But if you have access to the domain mentioned, you can use this scope which is the global scope for access to all domain settings.

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/auth.html):

> To request access using OAuth 2.0, your application needs the scope information, as well as information that Google supplies when you register your application (such as the client ID and the client secret).

Answer (score 0):

The old admin settings API is still working for SSO settings, just tried. You can manage the SSO settings of any organization that has enabled your project ID with the scope `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/` via a Marketplace install (they install your app) or a manual install as described [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)